# Wordpress: Looping field inside main-nav array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a WP-site with a custom Nav-menu.
Each page has ACF-fields repeater fields. I wish to make a scroll-to-sub-menu with by echoing a loop of all the fields of a specific page.
If I put the loop inside the `$mainNav` array, I get a php error.
I tried to start the loop before  the array, and end it after, but that just prints 1 (the last) `info_block_header`. 
Glad for any help :)

sidebar.php:

```
<nav id="mainNav">

            <?php 
                $mainNav = array(
               'theme_location'  => '',
               'menu'            => 'main-menu', 
               'container'       => 'ul', 
               'container_class' => 'topmenu-{topmenu slug}-container', 
               'container_id'    => 'topmenu',
               'menu_class'      => 'topmenu', 
               'menu_id'         => 'topmenu-{topmenu slug}[-{increment}]',
               'echo'            => true,
               'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
               'before'          => '',
               'after'           => '<ul id="about" class="dropDown">
                                        '. if(get_field('info_block')):
                                        while(has_sub_field('info_block')): .'
                                        <li><a href="#">'. get_sub_field('info_block_header') .'</a></li>'
                                        . endwhile; endif; .'
                                    </ul>',
               'link_before'     => '<h4>',
               'link_after'      => '</h4>',
               'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
               'depth'           => 0,
               'walker'          => ''
              );

            wp_nav_menu( $mainNav ); 

            ?>

                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Why not creating your own customized `wp menu walker` function?

Comment: Well, mainly because I don't really have the knowledge :)
I'll google a tutorial and see what I can do with that!

Comment: Can you extend the "after" instead of "walker"?

Comment: In a sort of a way, you can follow this tutorial which is very comprehensive.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401

Comment: So now I have made a custom walker, but I can't find any good documentation on how to loop an ACF-field inside the walker...